# how do I specify colour when using fill in ggplot2 and how to print pvalue onto plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(Isodecoder = c("Val", "Leu", "Ile", "Arg", "Ser", 
"Ala"), Anticodon = c("AAC", "AAG", "AAT", "ACG", "AGA", "AGC"
), baseMean = c(16330.2876073118, 280025.429470444, 47222.9145508434, 
639520.228162813, 591.699871418142, 194550.678700214), log2FC = c(0.241812205124871, 
0.062182487534649, -0.912898805851376, 0.414430653693951, -0.547252664766089, 
-0.576581451007797), lfcSE = c(0.330123826005643, 0.0835105091511506, 
0.193443262487333, 0.258705563545134, 0.211263611125761, 0.249830083859411
), stat = c(0.732489405719955, 0.744606734729653, -4.71920703834881, 
1.60193947132354, -2.59037825705024, -2.30789439806721), pvalue = c(0.463869906720502, 
0.45650949539292, 2.36765754572021e-06, 0.109168994996796, 0.00958705250629343, 
0.0210050107216242), FDR = c(0.585940934804845, 0.585940934804845, 
1.7165121174307e-05, 0.201542759994085, 0.030678568020139, 0.0591953931677063
), Label = c("Val-AAC", "Leu-AAG", "Ile-AAT", "Arg-ACG", "Ser-AGA", 
"Ala-AGC"), wobble = c("AT_wobble", "AT_wobble", "AT_wobble", 
"AT_wobble", "AT_wobble", "AT_wobble")), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

and I am plotting these as barplots within a larger loop. my barplot function is:

```
tRNA_barplot <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = Label, y = log2FC, fill = wobble, label = ifelse(FDR < 0.05, "*", "ns")))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
    geom_text(vjust = 0, nudge_y = ifelse(df2$log2FC < 0, -1, 1), size = ifelse(df2$FDR < 0.05, 6, 4))+
    xlab("Isoacceptor")+
    ylab(expression(paste(Log[2],"FC",sep="")))+
    #ylim(c(-5, 5))+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 45, hjust = 1), plot.margin = margin(0.5,0.5,0.5,2, "cm"), axis.title = element_text(size = 12))+
    ggtitle(iso, "Fed vs Starved - tRNA LFCs")
```

I've used fill = wobble to colour by wobble position. in barplots where both AT_wobble and GC_wobble are present ... AT_wobble is coloured red and GC_wobble is coloured blue/turquoise. How do I ensure GC_wobble remain blue/turquoise in barplots where it is plotted alone.

by the way ... by blue and red I mean the standard R colour output when not specified

Attached are examples of what i am talking about:

[image]

[image]

Leu is perfect but I would like plots like Pro to remain blue/turquoise for GC_wobble.

Also, I've specified that all FDR > 0.05 should have ns printed ontop of the barplot [ifelse(FDR < 0.05, "*", "ns")]. Is there a way to print the actual FDR number to 4 decimal places? I've tried numerous ways but they're all really messy.

Thanks!

Comment: 'iso' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to the two part question:

Part 1: Using the `scales` package you can determine the code for any default ggplot colour. I've set this out explicitly in a separate line to make it obvious, you could simplify by including this directly in the call to `scale_fill_manual`

Part 2: print the actual FDR number using a call to `geom_text`. Note adjustment to y scale to allow FDR text to avoid clashing with the plot boundary.

Some other points:
a) `geom_col()` is simpler than `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`
b) the call to `expression()` does not need to include `paste`, check out `?plotmath`
c) adjust asterisk size using an `ifelse` conditional statement for the call to `size`

```r
 
library(ggplot2)

col_GC_wobble <- scales::hue_pal()(2)[[2]]

scales::hue_pal()(2)[2]
#> [1] "#00BFC4"

ggplot(df2, aes(x = Label, y = log2FC, fill = wobble))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(FDR < 0.05, "*", round(FDR, 4))),
            vjust = ifelse(df2$log2FC < 0, 1, -0.2),
            size = ifelse(df2$FDR < 0.05, 10, 4))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_GC_wobble)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = 0.1))+
  xlab("Isoacceptor")+
  ylab(expression(Log[2]~FC))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        plot.margin = margin(0.5,0.5,0.5,2, "cm"), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12))+
  ggtitle("Fed vs Starved - tRNA LFCs")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Peter, I only want to add the FDR text if FDR > 0.05 ... if FDR < 0.05 then I would like it to remain as an asterisk ... how can I do this?

Comment: Answer updated with conditional FDR text

Comment: Apologies Peter, last question i promise ... how do I make the asterisk the same size as the fontsize of the p-values pasted ontop of the bar charts ... my asterisks are now tiny compared to the numbers

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `scale_fill_manual`. Look below.

```
tRNA_barplot <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = Label, y = log2FC, fill = wobble, label = ifelse(FDR < 0.05, "*", "ns")))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_text(vjust = 0, nudge_y = ifelse(df2$log2FC < 0, -1, 1), size = ifelse(df2$FDR < 0.05, 6, 4))+
  xlab("Isoacceptor")+
  ylab(expression(paste(Log[2],"FC",sep="")))+
  #ylim(c(-5, 5))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 45, hjust = 1), plot.margin = margin(0.5,0.5,0.5,2, "cm"), axis.title = element_text(size = 12))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("AT_wobble" = 5))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, Cheers mate ... ended up fixing it by using scale_fill_manual(values = c("GC_wobble" = "#00BFC4", "AT_wobble" = "#F8766D") ... to use the default colour scheme

Comment: I'm glad that I helped. Remember that on Stack Overflow you say thank you by selecting the approved solution.